# Making a Text Field a Link to a Sub-Report

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I have constructed a Crystal Report with several drill-down options depending on user selection, based upon a SQL stored procedure in my database.

I have a sub-report which is dependant on the variables clicked on by the users.

However, I was wondering if I could use text objects, rather than values read from my query, I attempted to fiddle around with 'Format Text' and making it a hyper-link, I think I'm on the right track but unsure where to go from here;

I.E. The data context etc...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the sub report in the main design window and select **Change Subreport Links...**
Set your sub report link to link to a formula field.  This will allow you to use any calculated value as a sub report link.

[image: Change Subreport Links]
[image: Set SubReport Links]

Comment: Thanks for your response - I'm close I think. I don't want this to be a parameter for users to be prompted for... The field simply has to be something which holds a value that can be applied to a value in my SQl query. For example, the text will say RED.. therefore my drill down will only return products with a colour RED when clicked..

Comment: This parameter will not show up for the users to see.  If you set the subreport parameter to be fed the value RED by the formula, it will silently take that value and apply it.  You can hide the subreport in a section that gets drilled down into.  That way it doesn't show up right away.

Comment: As soon as I make the parameter and insert it into the report it prompts for a value on run time. What particular setting when creating a parameter will solve this? Thanks

Comment: The key to all this is to work with just the sub report.  Once you have imported or created a sub report with the wizard, you can edit the sub report and add the parameter to the sub report.  This parameter will pop if not linked properly.  This is where you follow the directions above.  Is this working for you?